# How do i prove that $Res(F_n,0)=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$ with $F_n(z)= z^ne^\frac1z$

Tags: calculus, residue-calculus

I have $F_n(z)= z^ne^\frac1z$

and i've to prove that $Res(F_n,0)=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$

And i know that 
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} \frac{1}{z^n} = e^\frac{1}{z}$

but i don't know how to procede next...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

$$e^{\frac{1}{z}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}z^{-k}$$
and thus $$z^ne^{\frac{1}{z}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^{n-k}}{k!}.$$

For here, I think that you can easily find the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$ in the Laurent expansion.

Comment: i've calculated the series expansion at $z=\infty$

$z^n\left(1+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{2z^2}+\frac{1}{6z^3}+\frac{1}{24z^4}+{...}\right)$

But still i don't understand how the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$ is in anyway $\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$

(Thanks for your time)

Comment: $z^{n-k}=z^{-1}$ if $k=n+1$.